# Is it a coincidence that both Italian and German use third person feminine pronouns for formal second-person address?

Tags: etymology, pronouns, german, italian

In both Italian and German, the third person feminine pronouns ("lei" and "Sie," respectively) also serve as the formal second person pronoun.

Etymologically, is it a coincidence that both these languages reuse this specific pronoun for formal address (rather than a dedicated formal pronoun like "usted" in Spanish)?

Comment: _Sie_ is the Gm 3pl (all genders) form, as can be seen by its 3pl verb agreement. [3rd person is more polite than 2nd, and plural is more polite than singular.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/151925/15299)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Italian uses the third person feminine by following Spanish usage of *usted*. It simply never developed a special pronoun, which is reasonable as Italian very rarely uses the pronoun at all (e.g. *Cosa desidera?*, *Si accomodi, prego* etc.) and prefers to express the person via verbal agreement. It used to alternate with the *voi* form (2nd person plural), but it displaced it after WWII as the latter had a strong association with the Fascist regime. There is also a *loro* (3rd person plural) form but it's nowadays basically confined to satire, as it is perceided as comically stuffy.

The German *Sie* is not a 3rd person singular form - it is a 3rd person **plural** form (as can be seen from the verbal agreement) and so it has more to do with the Italian *loro* than with *lei*. It has a similar origin to *usted* in that it comes from an ellipsis of *Euer Gnaden*, which means something similar to *your grace* but it is plural (and so requires the 3rd person **plural** form). It displaced the *Ihr* form (2nd person plural) in the nineteenth century, although I'm not sure what prompted it.

The similarity with the feminine 3rd person pronoun *sie* in the German language is completely accidental and has, as best as I can tell, no relation with the Italian *lei* or the Spanish *usted*.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that Danish _De_ (= _Sie_) **is** based directly on the German pattern, so that at least is not coincidence.

Comment: Also, Italian _Lei_ as a formal pronoun also comes from a noun phrase like _vostra Signoria_ ‘your Lordship’, so the underlying process is the same for Italian, Spanish, Portuguese and German – it’s just that Spanish and Portuguese continued using the whole noun phrase (_vuestra merced_ / _vossa merce[d]e_), contracting them into shortened forms that eventually became separate pronouns (_usted_ / _você_); whereas German and Italian stopped using the noun phrases explicitly and instead started using existing anaphoric pronouns to implicitly refer to them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You're right that the *lei* form is actually native to Italy, however it was greatly popularized during the Spanish domination by the influence of *usted*, The strong "foreign" associations of *lei* was what prompted the Fascist regime to prefer the *voi* form and thus, ironically, what prompted the almost total dominance of *lei* after 1946. [Source](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/sui-pronomi-di-cortesia/179) (in Italian)

Comment: *Euer Gnaden* isn't plural IMHO but a (fossilized) genitive, same as "Liebfrauenkirche", "Kirche unser lieben Frauen", "Orangenmarmelade" &cpp. This is borne out by similar words "Euer Majestät", "Euer Hoheit" and that it can be used with singular and plural verbs: "Sind Euer Gnaden bereit?", "Ist Euer Gnaden bereit?", though plural may be strongly preferred when you're already using such hifalutin titles anyway.

Comment: "similarity with the feminine 3rd person pronoun sie [...] completely accidental"—hardly accidental I think. I'd guess it goes back to a tendency in older stages of these languages to re-cycle the feminine forms for the plural. Note that in German that the article ("der", "die", "das" -> "die") and adjectives tend to look like the f. form, cf. "schöner Mann", "schöne Frau", "schönes Kind" -> "schöne Männer", "schöne Frauen", "schöne Kinder" (i.e. plural forms re-cacly the f. singular adjective form).

Comment: @JohnFrazer With "accidental" I meant that there is no cross-linguistic trend that tend to use third person singular as respectful forms - it's a specific German(ic?) trend that tends to use the same words for 3rd person feminine and 3rd person plural. Point taken for *Eurer Gnaden*, I confess I'm less familiar with the story of German and I went by what I could find after a cursory research. What do you suggest is the reason for German to replace *Ihr* with *Sie*?

Comment: @Denis Nardin No idea other than, well, fashion. Hist:y there has also been Ihro Gnaden; also, in the 18th c Prussian nobility (and maybe elsewhere too) addressed the comman man in 3rd Sing. as in "hatt er denn noch nicht genug, (Wir Selbst wurden auch nur mit Biersuppe großgezogen)." (F.II.v.Pr.) which sounds like they're talking about s.o. else but form also used when speaking dangerously close to the face of the commoner (when hesitantly stammered in presence of the king, more like "Wenn Dehro Höchste Majestät geruhen wollten [...]" &cpp). Cf. Italy, also x-ling causes.